# Json integer value automatically converts to string value

Tags: java, json

When I send JSON request with integer value, it gets converted to string on the Java side automatically where the accepting field is of String type.
I am using Jersey Jackson API for JSON handling.
e.g.,

**JSON request**:

```
{
   "executable":1
}
```

Here I am sending integer value to string type executable variable.
But it is accepting the integer value and converting it to string.

What my requirement is strict validation for data types.

Comment: You are sending a JSON String. So everything in that JSON is on String. You can convert that to int in JAVA side.

Comment: Is there any way of this validation without explicit type conversion on the JAVA side?

Comment: Yeah you can create an Entity depending on your JSON and you can use ObjectMapper(for eg) , which wil convert your json to the entity. No need to use any conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could make changes according to my requirements.
My requirement was to validate the JSON request against the JSON schema.
It is true that JSON request comes as string so I cannot validate directly, so I accept the request as string and validate against schema using json-schema-validator.

Answer (score 1):

All values of a json object are strings. You need to cast it yourself.

```
Integer.valueOf(STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_CONVERT);
```

You can use JsonDeserializer as well. There is a example here:[Error in Android JsonDeserializer when returning response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989026/error-in-android-jsondeserializer-when-returning-response/36989414?noredirect=1#comment61584112_36989414)

Comment: True but I need validation of the json string sent.

Comment: Hhmm you can validate in both ways. What do you mean by validating by schema?

Comment: I mean is there a way to fail the validation if an integer value is passed in the JSON request which is mapped to a string value in Java POJO class?